# Sorting NSString values as if NSInteger using NSSortDescriptor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nssortdescriptor

I have created a sort descriptor to sort a plist response coming from my server. This works well with sort key having values upto 9. With more than 10 items I see abrupt results with sort key arranged in the order = 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sort" ascending:YES];
self.myList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[unsortedList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]]];
```

How to make it arrange in the correct order of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do this by implementing a custom comparator block when creating your `NSSortDescriptor`:

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sort" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
self.myList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[unsortedList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]]];
```

See Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: please note that this solution will not work with CoreData fetchRequests, because it doesn't accept descriptors based on blocks.

Answer (score 39):

`[list sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];` will sort the list in a "human" way (so "11" will come last, not between "1" and "2"). But if you really do want to treat these strings as numbers, you should make them number first!

Comment: perfect! other solutions didn't work for me, because CoreData doesn't accept sortDescriptors based on blocks. but this one worked.

Comment: The best solution for me;)

Answer (score 16):

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sort.intValue" ascending:YES];
self.myList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[unsortedList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]]];
```

Sort based on the value of the integer.

Comment: Perfect with it's simplicity!

Comment: didn't work. i get '0 1 10 11 12 ... 2 3 4' instead of '0 1 2 3 4 ... 10 11 12'

Comment: Simplest answer. Worked for integer values very well

Answer (score 11):

You need your strings to be compared with the [`NSNumericSearch`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSNumericSearch) option:

> `NSNumericSearch`
> Numbers within strings are compared using numeric value, that is, `Name2.txt` < `Name7.txt` < `Name25.txt`.

which requires the [`compare:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare:options:) method to be called for the comparison.

In order to do that, your sort descriptor can use an [`NSComparator` Block](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW6):

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self"
                              ascending:YES
                             comparator:^(NSString * string1, NSString * string2){
                                            return [string1 compare:string2
                                                            options:NSNumericSearch];
 }];
```

Or, indeed, you can skip the sort descriptor and simply [sort the array directly](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW28), using the same Block:

```
[unsortedList sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult (NSString * string1, NSString * string2){
    return [string1 compare:string2
                    options:NSNumericSearch];
 }];
```

Comment: Small addition: Why casting to `NSString`? You could pass `NSString` directly instead of `id`, makes it easier to read. :-)

Comment: please note that this solution will not work with CoreData fetchRequests, because it doesn't accept descriptors based on blocks.

Answer (score 7):

```
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"11",@"2",@"3",@"1", nil];
[list sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSInteger firstInteger = [obj1 integerValue];
    NSInteger secondInteger = [obj2 integerValue];
    if( firstInteger > secondInteger) return NSOrderedDescending;
    if( firstInteger == secondInteger) return NSOrderedSame;
    return NSOrderedAscending; // edited
}];
```

No guarantees about performance

Comment: please note that this solution will not work with CoreData fetchRequests, because it doesn't accept descriptors based on blocks.

Answer (score 0):

All the above methods need good knowledge of basics to implement; but for the newbies I suggest the simplest way – to use the native block method

```
NSArray* sortedArr =[fetchResults sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {

    int aValue = [[a valueForKey:@"subgroupId"] intValue];
    int bValue = [[b valueForKey:@"subgroupId"] intValue];

    return aValue > bValue;
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

input

```
{
    "seats": [{
        "seatNumber": "1"
    }, {
        "seatNumber": "10"
    }, {
        "seatNumber": "2"
    }]
}
```

sort using [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"seatNumber" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]]. The key is to use localizedStandardCompare. This will solve you problem.

```
NSArray *seats = [self.seats sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"seatNumber" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]]];
```

output

```
{
    "seats": [{
        "seatNumber": "1"
    }, {
        "seatNumber": "2"
    }, {
        "seatNumber": "10"
    }]
}
```

documentation: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1409742-localizedstandardcompare

Comment: You should not just answer with code, but try to give a description/explanation of what it does, how it solves the problem, etc...