# How to sort NSMutableArray which contain object as data using amount

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a NSMutableArray which contain object as data which hold three value, Which is date,name,and amount.

So my array look like this

```
date   name   amount
08/12  atest  1000
08/13  btest  200
08/14  ctest  3000
08/15  dtest  4000
08/13  etest  5000
```

Now I'm sorting the data using this code

For amount

```
[tableAry sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"amount" 
ascending:NO selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];
```

But it says that my 200 record is larger than 1000 record sorted data is like this :

```
5000
4000
3000
200
1000
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting NSString values as if NSInteger using NSSortDescriptor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674707/sorting-nsstring-values-as-if-nsinteger-using-nssortdescriptor)

Comment: Your original question had a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943970/nssortdescriptor-sort-with-number-as-string (which has been removed by an editor). Why did that not help?

Comment: @MartinR You are right that i have asked similar question before and not deleted by editor but i have delete it myself because problem is caused because of small typo in my code and i have solved it by correcting Spelling mistake. But i have not tested my sort function and when i tested it i have seen that my code do sorting in amount but not as expected so i have re posted this question with different data.In my first question is about date sorting that worked and my second question is about the not sorting amount data properlly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the amounts are stored as `NSString` values. You could fix it the way described in the answer that you linked (i.e. by replacing string representations of numbers with numeric ones stored as `NSNumber`), or work around it by adding `intValue` to the descriptor:

```
[tableAry sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"amount.intValue" ascending:NO]]];
```

Comment: But you would probably compare the integers without using `selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)`.

Comment: @MartinR You're right! I know I should read what I copy-paste, but I make this mistake again and again. Thanks!

Comment: Despite having suggested my own answer, I've up voted this one. Much more elegant than the answer I suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing the amounts as strings, not as numbers. The string `200` is 'greater' than the string `1000` by alphabetical sorting rules.

This is a classic "sorting numbers as strings" bug.

The answer to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943970/nssortdescriptor-sort-with-number-as-string) you referred to is exactly how you solve the problem.