# Why my sorting method using NSSortDescriptor doesn't work well?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor

I filter my table result using `NSPredicate`

```
   NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"Name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR Address CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                                    searchText,
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (key in dict) {

        if ([resultArray containsObject:key]) {

            NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:key];
            matches = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

            if (matches.count > 0) {

                [searchResults addObjectsFromArray:matches];
                // sorting array
                NSSortDescriptor *sort=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Distance" ascending:YES];
                [searchResults sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
            }

        }
    }

    }
```

Then I sort result array using `NSSortDescriptor`

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Distance" ascending:YES];
                [searchResults sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

It is working, but not for all results:

[image]

Comment: what do the raw values for distance look like? are they numbers, strings? is everything normalized to meters?

Comment: NSString *dist = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f km", distance/1000];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sort is incorrect because it interprets `Distance` as a string, not as a number. Strings are ordered *lexicographically*, meaning that `100.00 km` comes in front of `2.00 km`, because `1`, the initial digit of `100.00 km`, is less than `2`, the initial digit of `2.00 km`.

You can fix it by using `NSNumber` in place of `NSString` when representing distances, or forcing the same number of digits by padding all values with zeros to achieve the same length.

Comment: Ok, can you add an example of sorting by number?

Comment: @PavelKaljunen Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9674876/335858), it provides an example of how to deal with this without changing the data that you store in the `Distance` property.

Answer (score 2):

You should sort on a number, which is the normalised distance in meters, not the display string (sorting strings with numbers in requires different logic).